# Azure Mobile service : where is application key

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

where i can retrieve application key from my mobile service instance ?

Thank you.

Julien

Comment: Where do you want to find your application key? During development? At runtime in the client? At runtime in the server? If the latter, which kind of server are you running (JavaScript or .NET)?

Answer (score 11):

If you go to your Mobile Service in Azure and click on the configure tab

[image: config tab]

At the bottom of the screen this ribbon will appear

[image: buttons on ribbon]

If you click on 'manage keys' then it will show you your app keys[image: app keys]

Comment: thanks for the answer, it took me forever to find that - I wonder why they decided to put that on the bottom next to restart and delete... very bad UI

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Mobile Service in Azure and at the bottom Manage Keys option is there,
you can get it from there.
[image]